# How to backup mysql database every 10 minutes

Tags: mysql

I want to backup MySQL database every 10 minutes. how i can do it. I don't know how to use procedure or function for it.
I have used

```
mysqldump -u root -p mydatabase > mydb_backup.sql
```

I also want to add date and time in end of backup database name. I should only keep latest 3 backup database in system and destroy other database.

Comment: You can use `cron job` for firing the command every 10 minutes.

Comment: i don't have any idea how to do it

Answer (score 1):

How about a backup every second?  Well, actually it is "continually".  It is called "Replication".

You build another mysql server (machine) as the Slave.

Then copy the data to the Slave, and do CHANGE MASTER on the Slave to have it continually replicate from the Master (which is your current instance of mysql).

Answer (score 0):

**[AutoMySQLBackup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/) has some great features to:**

backup a single database, multiple databases, or all the databases on the server;

each database is saved in a separate file that can be compressed (with gzip or bzip2);

it will rotate the backups and not keep them filling your hard drive (as normal in the daily backup you will have only the last 7 days of backups, the weekly if enabled will have one for each week, etc.).

or you can find more info here   [10 Ways to Automatically & Manually Backup MySQL Database](http://www.noupe.com/development/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html)

Comment: I want to write my own procedure not any third party software and i don't use linux

Comment: you can find here more info http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/using-php-to-backup-mysql-databases.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in unix or linux you can use `crontab` for scheduling.
To add the the time and date to the backup file you can use a syntax similar to the following

```
mysqldump -u root -p mydatabase > mydb_backup_`date+"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`.sql
```